# Polynomials passing through points with tangential conditions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields, additive-combinatorics

In corollary here http://math.mit.edu/~lguth/Exposition/erdossurvey.pdf on polynomial methods it is said "(Parameter counting) If $S\subset\mathbb F^n$ is a finite set, then there is a non-zero polynomial that vanishes on $S$ with degree $\leq n|S|^{1/n}$" ($\mathbb F$ is a field).

It seems that if we include the phrase "such that a fraction $r\in[0,1]$ of them satisfy no tangential conditions at those points" then there should be no change in the degree.

However if we include the phrase "such that a fraction $r\in[0,1]$ of them satisfy tangential conditions at those points" then the degree might blow up.

Is there a bound on degree if we also the phrase "such that a fraction $r\in[0,1]$ of them satisfy tangential conditions at those points"? I am intereseted in $r\rightarrow1$.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field: am I right?

Comment: @Armandoj18eos No document refers only 'Field' terminology.